# Using Firestore on a watch consumes a lot of power. Is there an optimization solution?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, watch

```
 val collection = db.collection("users_test_1")
    collection
        .add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference> { documentReference ->
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.id
            )
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e) })
    collection.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ${snapshot?.documents}")
    }
```

[Power consumption test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxzKg.jpg)

Using Firestore on a watch consumes a lot of power. Is there an optimization solution?

Comment: You may listen when `onResume` and remove when `onPause` (depends activity or fragment in your case). No special code for `Firestore` here.

Comment: I need to monitor the changes of Firestore data in the background, just like the server disables the phone function, and without monitoring, the power consumption will also increase. This has a great impact on the small battery capacity of the watch.

Comment: I guess that is a great feature of your app. However, continuous listen in background is not the best idea. How about restart listen after a special period using `WorkManager`, [see this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#schedule_periodic_work)